# rails 4 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError attributes as variable fail, attributes spelled out success

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

in model Artist:

Edited to reflect misunderstandings in comments.

Dog.poop is just my silly way of using colorize to get a more visible puts output. It only eats strings, that is why Dog.poop("#{}")

Dog.poop(#{attributes == {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}"

is just to show I checked if attributes is indeed == with the {"firstname etc Hash. is true (=== is true too)

because of what follows

Example 1: Trying to make a new Artist object, feeding in variable attributes from function argument. Fails.

```
def self.a_new_one(attributes)
    Dog.poop(#{attributes == {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}"
    # --> true

    Dog.poop("#{self.new(attributes)}")
    # --> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
end
```

BUT:

Example 2: Trying to make a new Artist object, feeding in the {"firstname etc Hash. Succeeds.

This is weird, if attributes=={{"firstname etc Hash is true!

```
def self.a_new_one(attributes)
    Dog.poop(#{attributes == {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}"
    # --> true

    Dog.poop("#{self.new({"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"})}")
    # --> #<Artist:0x007fe39ee2cc08>
end
```

AND this works too:

Example 3: If I make the object by passing the attributes into a block and adding them one by one, then also: Success.

WHY? why Fail in ex 1, but success in ex2 and ex3?

```
def self.a_new_one(attributes)
    Dog.poop(#{attributes == {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}"
    # --> true

    self.new do |artist|
        attributes.each do |key, value|
            artist[key] = value
        end
        Dog.poop("#{artist}")
        # --> #<Artist:0x007fe39ee2cc08>
    end
end
```

WHY? What am I not getting here? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, balance your quotes and brackets (as suggested by beartech's answer). Then let's see.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this is not what is going on. attributes is the argument passed into the function call. I am checking (with the == line that you are both commenting on) that the attributes is really equal (it even is ===) with the firstname etc Hash. What I don't understand is why, if I instantiate a new Artist object, why it works if I pass the firstname Hash in, but not if I pass the attribute variable/argument in, yet again it works if I use attribute variable with the block in the third example.

Comment: Thanks! There was a " missing as you observed. So my Dog is pooping properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `==` for variable assignment then use variable interpolation to get those into the object.

```
Dog.poop(#{attributes == {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}"
```

You are also missing `)` at the end of the above line and have an extra double quote at the very end.

I think what you really meant to do is:

```
    Dog.poop("#{attributes = {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}")

$> attributes
     => {"firstname"=>"Firstname",
     "lastname"=>"Lastname",
     "description"=>"test",
     "document_id"=>"",
     "email"=>"",
     "mobile"=>"",
     "url"=>"",
     "soloist"=>"1",
     "performance_order"=>"1"}
```

Still not sure why you are doing it that way, it doesn't make sense to me, but maybe you can explain. If `attributes` is being passed to the method then why would you then override it?

Or are you checking to see if the `attributes` being passed in matches what you were expecting, then saving? In that case I think it's just a case of the missing `"` at the beginning before `#{attributes...`.

```
Dog.poop("#{attributes == {"firstname"=>"Firstname", "lastname"=>"Lastname", "description"=>"test", "document_id"=>"", "email"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "url"=>"", "soloist"=>"1", "performance_order"=>"1"}}")
```

Is basically just:

```
Dog.poop(true)
```

Why are you doing that, it is not clear from your code.

Comment: And not sure what you are trying to do with `#{` in that code. Unless you are trying to interpolate some variables, in which case you are actually missing a double quote at the beginning to match the extra one on the end?

Comment: The first `poop` call (the one with the `==`) is for the logging. It shows that the `attributes` does indeed equal that hash.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this is not what is going on. attributes is the argument passed into the function call. I am checking (with the == line that you are both commenting on) that the attributes is really equal (it even is ===) with the firstname etc Hash. What I don't understand is why, if I instantiate a new Artist object, why it works if I pass the firstname Hash in, but not if I pass the attribute variable/argument in, yet again it works if I use attribute variable with the block in the third example.

Comment: Sorry, I did miss a " as you wrote!

Comment: So was the answer the missing `"` ?

Comment: Looks like it. That was definitely a mistake. Tried to replicate, because it still doesn't make sense, but of course, I have moved on now and found a totally different solution for the actual problem I was having. Thanks for spotting the missing " in my pooping Dog!

Comment: Also not quite getting why I got a true for the == question. It should have come with an Error as it does now? Weird